# UITableView reloadData not working on MainTable in Split View Controller

Tags: uitableview, ios7, uisplitviewcontroller

I have a feature in my app where the user can change the color scheme of the app. The app uses a Split View Controller, with a MainTable and DetailView table. Everything works fine except for the MainTable. What is failing is that the MainTable reloadData method is not causing the cells to be redrawn.

It should be noted that I am changing globalHighContrast and sending the notification from a UIModalPresentationFormSheet viewController, so the tables are kind of visible on the screen while the viewController is active.

I am triggering the screen update from a notification, like this:

```
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(reloadAllTables)
                                                 name:@"contrastModeChanged"
                                               object:nil];
```

Then, to make sure that I call reloadData on the main thread, I am handling the notification like this:

```
-(void)reloadAllTables{

    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(doReloadAllTables) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}

-(void)doReloadAllTables{

    [self showIcon];

    if( globalHighContrast ){
        theTable.backgroundColor = [Colors lightBkgColor];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [Colors lightBkgColor];
    } else {
        theTable.backgroundColor = [Colors darkBkgColor];
        self.view.backgroundColor = [Colors darkBkgColor];
    }

    [detailViewController configureView:currentMainMenu];
    [detailViewController.subTable reloadData];

    [theTable reloadData];

    // desperate try to force it to work
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:currentMainMenu inSection:0];
    [self tableView:theTable didSelectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
}
```

Both reloadAllTables and doReloadAllTables are being called, but

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

is not being called.

As soon as I tap a cell on the MainTable it does update correctly to the new color scheme.

Also, there is a desperate attempt to workaround this by trying to simulate the MainTable touch, but that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to put code for updating you scheme in `-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` method...